# se generan 2 correos usando mail.sender en appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive, gmail

muy buen dia tengo un pequeño inconveniente con Google Apps Script y es que cuando yo mando un formulario con jotform lo pasa a un sheets ese google sheets cada vez que se actualiza agarra la última fila y toma los datos para después enviarlos por correo electrónico es ahí donde se envía 2 veces el mismo documento uno como el mensaje enviado pero el otro se envía como compartido es ahí donde yace mi problema este es mi codigo:

```js
function MailSender(Client){
  var Message = "este es solo una prueba de pdf, descarga aquí el pdf: " + Client.PDF;
  MailApp.sendEmail(Client.Mail, "documento prueba", Message);
}
```

pero en ningún lado del script puse que se compartiera y se mande pero me manda 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se añadió al script un pedazo de api de este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189936/share-a-drive-document-without-notifying-user-with-google-apps-script/25298083#25298083

es de la api de Advanced Drive Service y pues elimino uno... pero no el que se requería
es el que está en rojo el que quiero evitar que se mande :/// alguna sugerencia o ¿alguna idea de como puedo evitar esto? gracias de antemano c:

Comment: En el menú de recursos de App Script puedes indicarle que no te mande notificaciones, seteándolo a `false`, revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25298083/5587982) para más detalles.

Comment: muchas gracias lo voy a checar aun asi gracias :)

Comment: pues si lo quita un email pero hace lo diametralmente opuesto que es quitar el mail de notificacion y deja el compartido, lo cual yo quiero lo opuesto, deja actualizo post

Comment: listo, ya actualize... pero veo que en una parte del script del link que mandaste hay una parte que dice "sendNotificationEmails" y elimina el mail que quiero poner no el que necesito eliminar pero... hay algo asi como "sendsharedmail" o algo asi?

Comment: En verdad no entiendo del todo tu contexto. Yo tengo algo parecido, es un formulario que recoge datos, el mismo está ligado a un GoogleSheet, y en el código de ese GoogleSheet yo tengo un evento `onChange(e)` que es desde donde escucho los cambios del formulario, y envío un email cuando esto ocurre. Ahora bien, yo no mando archivos compartidos, sino simple texto. Mi pregunta es, ¿has revisado que no hay más eventos que se disparan, desde el formulario o desde la hoja ligada al mismo?

Comment: Agrega un [mcve] (no está claro cómo es llamada la función `MailSender`, cómo se define el parámetro `Client`)